# SQL/Pyspark - to check condition

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with customer Id, Date of purchase

I wanted to check if there is 3 purchase in the 5 days windows period.

Note : Doesn't need to be consecutive

> | Cust Id | Date O Purchase |
> | --- | --- |
> | 11 | 09/11/2023 |
> | 11 | 13/11/2023 |
> | 11 | 15/11/2023 |
> | 11 | 21/11/2023 |
> | 11 | 23/11/2023 |
> | 11 | 24/11/2023 |
> | 12 | 16/11/2023 |
> | 12 | 21/11/2023 |
> | 12 | 25/11/2023 |
> | 12 | 01/12/2023 |
> | 12 | 03/12/2023 |
> | 12 | 05/12/2023 |

Considering the table as the input for checking any 3 days out of 5 days window.
For cust id 11 ->

1. DOP 9/11/2023 + 5 days window period is 14/11/2023

   - On checking it has only 2 days 9/11/2023 & 13/11/2023 so it fails
2. DOP 13/11/2023 + 5 days window period is 18/11/2023 - Fails(only 2 record)
3. DOP 15/11/2023 + 5 days window period is 20/11/2023 - Fails(only 1 record)
4. **DOP 21/11/2023 + 5 days window period is 26/11/2023**

   - On checking it has 3 days 21/11/2023,23/11/2023 & 24/11/2023 so it passes

On the overall level - CustomerID 11 passes the condition of having any 3 days purchase in the 5 days windows period

Please let me know if the question or clear.

Comment: Perhaps you are overcomplicating this logic and all you need is a counting rows belonging to a certain customer within a 5-day daterange specified in the where clause.

Comment: The consecutive part of the question looks irrelevant - you just want 3 purchase in the 5 days windows period ? but what if there are more than 3?

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks, overlaps can still be accepted just wanted to see if there minimum of 3 purchase in 5 days window. Since finally I'm looking for the shortlisted customers

Comment: @Shadow thanks, For Example : dates are not always regular ,so row number considers Nov12th and Dec8th as 1 and 2 but the date gap is not the 5 days duration.. If you have a way around could you please suggest

Comment: I suggest you discard the linked question which doesn't seem appropriate to your requirement and add sample data and desired outcome as text.

Comment: Thanks @P.Salmon I 've removed the linked question and formatted the requirements better. Please suggest if it needs a external files for sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at this problem differently to simplify the solution, for each 3 consecutive purchases check if one of them is in the range of 5 days, and to simplify it even more after ordering the data by "Date O Purchase" you only need to check current row and current row -2 in that order (this means the last 3 purchase) and check if the dates of these 2 rows are within 5 days, here's a solution in PySpark:

```
w = Window.partitionBy("Cust_Id").orderBy("Date_Of_Purchase")
df = df.withColumn("Date_Of_Purchase", to_date(col("Date_Of_Purchase"), "dd/MM/yyyy")) \
    .withColumn("Prev_Date_Of_Purchase", lag("Date_Of_Purchase", 2).over(w)) \
    .withColumn("days_between", datediff(col("Date_Of_Purchase"), col("Prev_Date_Of_Purchase")))
df.show()

df.filter(col("days_between") <= 5).select("Cust_Id").distinct().show()
```

**EDIT:**

You can generalize this by changing the 2 in `lag("Date_Of_Purchase", 2)` to the number of purchases - 1, and the 5 in `.filter(col("days_between") <= 5)` the to days interval le window.

Comment: Thanks, for simplifying the solution. I checked the code and noticed that days_between checks the date date difference between current and previous-2  & filter condition <=3 Its getting validated just to check if there is another purchase within 3 days . 

Just wanted to confirm so the filter condition should be <=3 days as we are looking at 3 days before, 5 days window period is already getting taken care here ?

Comment: @MooventhChiyan I'm not sure if I understand your question, this check if any 3 purchases are in the 5 days window interval not 3 days window interval.

Comment: yes, I'm alligned with your response.. 3 purchase are in the 5 days window interval. From the code perspective, Please confirm if my understanding is correct  ->prev_date_of_purchase (lag=2 takes case of the 3 purchase)  the days_between filter <=5 checks within the 5 days

Comment: @MooventhChiyan Yes exactly

Comment: awesome thanks a lot